# Node.js error: [Error: Query is required]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post

I've been working on a project recently and it requires me to POST the required name to my profile.js file, but when I do `console.log(req.body.bookName)` (because the data I'm sending is called bookName), it gives me the error of `[Error: Query is required]`

Here is the post part of my profile.js code

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
if(req.session && req.session.user){
    Book.find({ owner: req.session.user.username || req.session.user }, function(err, book){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        books.search(req.body.search, options, function(error, results) {
            if ( ! error ) {
                console.log(req.body.bookName);
                res.render("profile",{
                    authenticated: true,
                    info: books,
                    results: results
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    });
}
else{
    res.status(401).send('You must be logged in to access this page');
}
})
```

Here is my button in my .ejs file

```
<form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." required class="searchBook">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ %>
        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="column four wide">
                <div class="ui card">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src = "<%= results[i].thumbnail %>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h1 class="ui small header title"><%= results[i].title %></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <p>Author: <%= results[i].authors %></p>
                            <p>Published on: <%= results[i].publishedDate %></p>
                            <p>Pages: <%= results[i].pageCount %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content extra">
                        <button id="detail" class="<%= results[i].title %>">View Detail</button>
                        <button class="ui button fluid" type="button" name="button">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="modaldiv" class="ui modal" style="position: relative">
            <i class="close icon"></i>
            <div class="header"><%=results[i].title%></div>
            <div class="content"><%=results[i].description%></div>
        </div><!-- Should be out side of the book info div -->
    <% } %>
```

And here is my home.js file where I post my data

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$(document).on("click", "#detail", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/profile',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: { bookName: $(this).attr("class")},
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
            alert("done");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Does anyone know why this error happens and how I can solve it?

Comment: Is your router prefixed with `/profile`? If not, it should be `router.post('/profile', ...)`.

Comment: Have you attached `body-parser`? And why do you send data to server as text instead of json?

Comment: @ZeroCho, yes I do have ```body-parser``` in my server.js file, and I send data to server as text instead of json because I intend to use the text to be used in the books.search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment, I found the issue.

What you send to the server is JSON not text.
`{ bookName: $(this).attr("class")}` is JSON not text. Of course, value of bookName is a text, but whole data is JSON.

you should

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/profile',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ bookName: $(this).attr("class")}),
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
            alert("done");
        }
    });
```

I believe you attached `bodyParser.json()` to express.
Then, console.log `req.body` on the '/profile' router. You will see body as JSON.

EDIT: one more thing I've found is that you did't send `req.body.search`
It should be something like `JSON.stringify({ bookName: $(this).attr("class"), search: $('.searchBook').val() })` That's why you got Error message.

EDIT2: You are trying to send form and AJAX simultaneously. It doesn't work like that. Just choose one thing. Form or AJAX. I recommend you to use AJAX. Cancel default behavior of form by using e.preventDefault() in `$(document).on('click')`

Answer (score 1):

Look at your query param. You are passing in this line `books.search(req.body.search,` if you notice, `req.body.search`is the query param but `search` is not defined in the body that you are posting: `{ bookName: $(this).attr("class")}`, only bookname.

I believe you intend to use: `books.search(req.body.bookName...`.

Update:

So I see you have a form that you post with search. The problem is that when that is posted, `req.body.search` is defined but not `req.body.bookName`. When then you click `#detail`, it is a brand new request where search is not being posted. At that point you will need to grab the value of `search` and post it as part of the same request. 
As individual request, one contains `bookName`, the other `search` but with the code in your current state, they aren't posted together as the nodejs endpoint expects it.

Hope this is of help.

Comment: Hi @Juan, req.body.search is another form that I POST, and it is defined. I'll update my .ejs file above